# CSF is blocking so many IP's

Tags: firewalls, information-gathering

I have been using DigitalOcean's services for about 2 years and CSF reported port blocking alerts twice a week. After I changed my country (and also the IP address of the machine changed) I am getting so many port scanning alerts every 5 minutes.

I haven't changed my CSF configuration and this drives me crazy.

Is this normal by just changing IP address?

#### Sample csf.deny:

```
118.255.45.161 # lfd: *Port Scan* detected from 118.255.45.161 (CN/China/Hunan/Changsha/-). 4 hits in the last 35 seconds - Sun Oct  2 11:16:54 2016
189.207.89.118 # lfd: *Port Scan* detected from 189.207.89.118 (MX/Mexico/Nuevo Leon/Monterrey/-). 4 hits in the last 15 seconds - Sun Oct  2 11:39:56 2016
36.6.87.204 # lfd: *Port Scan* detected from 36.6.87.204 (CN/China/Anhui/Hefei/-). 4 hits in the last 45 seconds - Sun Oct  2 12:15:31 2016
222.46.26.91 # lfd: *Port Scan* detected from 222.46.26.91 (CN/China/Beijing/Beijing/-). 4 hits in the last 20 seconds - Sun Oct  2 12:45:10 2016
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your IP address was being used by someone, who was already under attack (like using financial or banking transactions), thats why you are target of such attacks. but dont worry, as CSF is blocking IPs, you are safe. most of these port scans are automatic bots, they are not targetted attacks to gain access to your server. try to keep yourself updated with latest patches , open least ports, (if you have web application, then use WAF). you should be good to go then

Comment: I agree that OP is probably safe.  But disagree, that he is using an IP that has been used by someone with enough profile to trigger competent attacks.  The IPv4 address space is small enough for current computing speed to trigger completely random scans on completely inconspicuous addresses.  It is just that some addresses are more commonly used than others, for random reasons.  It is a decent answer though.